# Supporting Android material design

Tags: android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop

We're redesigning our android app and a question rises considering the upcoming Android L platform with its material style: what are the ways of supporting older devices? Will this new design be acceptable on 4.x devices?

Comment: It's probably too early to ask this kind of questions..

Comment: There will be an SDK for Android L later this 26th. You'll have time to find out. Anyway, I smell a 100k visits question

Comment: google.com/design there already some information about material design. /edit: for web there already a implementation in polymer -> polymer-project.org

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [Android Material Design compatibility docs](http://developer.android.com/preview/material/compatibility.html)

I'm going to rehash the material here incase the link gets taken down, which most likely it will be in the near future.

For the Material theme

> The material theme is only available in the Android L Developer
>   Preview. To configure your app to use the material theme on devices
>   running the Android L Developer Preview and an older theme on devices
>   running earlier versions of Android:
>
> Define a theme that inherits from an older theme (like Holo) in
>   res/values/styles.xml. Define a theme with the same name that inherits
>   from the material theme in res/values-v21/styles.xml. Set this theme
>   as your app's theme in the manifest file.

As for layouts

> If the layouts that you design according to the material design
>   guidelines do not use any of the new XML attributes from the Android L
>   Developer Preview, they will work on previous versions of Android.
>   Otherwise, you can provide alternative layouts. You can also provide
>   alternative layouts to customize how your app looks on earlier
>   versions of Android.
>
> Create your layout files for the Android L Developer Preview inside
>   res/layout-v21/ and your alternative layout files for earlier versions
>   of Android inside res/layout/. Alternative layouts have the same file
>   name.
>
> To avoid duplication of code, define your styles inside res/values/
>   and modify the styles in res/values-v21/ for the new APIs.

For UI Widgets

> The RecyclerView and CardView widgets are included in the Android L
>   Developer Preview Support Library, so they are available in earlier
>   versions of Android with these limitations:
>
> CardView falls back to a programmatic shadow implementation using
>   additional padding. CardView does not clip its children views that
>   intersect with rounded corners. These limitations do not apply to the
>   Android L Developer Preview.

and lastly for Animations

> The following new APIs are only available in the Android L Developer
>   Preview:
>
> Activity transitions, Touch feedback, Reveal animations, Path-based
>   animations. To preserve compatibility with earlier verisons of Android,
>   check the system version at runtime before you invoke these APIs.

Answer (score 2):

**The v7 Support Libraries r21 and above includes the following material design features:**

- Material design styles for some system widgets when you apply one of
  the Theme.AppCompat themes.
- Color palette theme attributes in the    Theme.AppCompat themes.
- The RecyclerView widget to display data    collections.
- The CardView widget to create cards. The Palette class    to extract
  prominent colors from images.

**The following features are available only in Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above:**

- Activity transitions
- Touch feedback
- Reveal animations
- Path-based animations
- Vector drawables
- Drawable tinting

Hence you can use some third party library available for Touch feedback. And can use custom activity transition animation. I have done custom activity transition animation. you can find my app on this [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=spi.infiniteshiv.in.spiritualinstruction)
.You can find youtube video of devebyte on custom activity transition.

Answer (score 0):

The support libraries includes many components using the new material design, especially since the release of the Design Support library. Using `Theme.AppCompat` (and similar) as a first step you will be on your way. Parts to include in your build.gradle are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:{{VERSION}}'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:{{VERSION}}'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:{{VERSION}}'
compile 'com.android.support:design:{{VERSION}}'
```

for version `22.2.0` or higher.

Also check out [AppCompat v21 — Material Design for Pre-Lollipop Devices](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) and [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).